# Go back to Main Activity on menu item click

Tags: android, menu, android-activity

My main activity is continuously receiving data from client. It has three menu items on top right corner which are About , Settings and Home . These three menu tabs are visible in all the three screens i.e. Home Screen(MainActivity class), About page and Settings page.
 On click of Home menu item , I have written following code

```
    case R.id.menu_Home:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

My question is if I click Home menu item from any screen , am I restarting my activity? If yes then please provide me some guidance on how to go to main activity screen on clicking Home menu item without restarting it, as I can not afford to loose data by restarting the activity again and again .

Comment: Are "Settings" and "About" also activities?

Answer (score 1):

You should never relay on a Activity as the data source, because it can be killed any time by the OS. You can use `SharedPreferences`, `LiteSQL` or anything else for saving Activity state and recreate it using this data inside your `onResume` method.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing in MainActivity aside, you could do this:

1. In MainActivity, start your other activities with:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, AboutPage.class);
   startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
   ```

   and

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsPage.class);
   startActivityForResult(intent, 20);
   ```
2. In each of those 2 called activities, do this:

   ```
   case R.id.menu_Home:
       setResult(SOME_NUMBER_FROM_ABOUT);
       finish();
   ```

   or

   ```
   case R.id.menu_Home:
       setResult(SOME_NUMBER_FROM_SETTINGS);
       finish();
   ```

   which will take you back to MainActivity.
3. Override onActivityResult() in your MainActivity:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

       switch(requestCode) {
           case 10:
               //handle returning from About page
               //you can also check for resultCode
               //if (resultCode == SOME_NUMBER_FROM_ABOUT) {
               //    some code here
               //}
               break;

           case 20:
               //handle returning from Settings page
               break;    
       }
   ```

Just remember to adjust this your class names, and SOME_NUMBER_FROM_ABOUT is an int which you can choose whatever you want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are restarting and creating a new instance of your main activity.
This might be helpful:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

In main activity, you don't need to do anything when home option is selected from the menu as the main activity is already loaded and running. Your current code will create and start a new instance of activity.

```
//in MainActivity
case R.id.menu_Home: 
    break;
```

You should also consider removing the home option form the menu on your main activity as its kind of useless. This can be accomplished by creating different menu without the home option for and inflating if from the main activity.

In all other activities your existing code should work fine.
However, if you use finish() each activity before loading any new activity except when you are in the main activity, your activity stack will be consist only of main activity and currently running activity. In this case you can use the following code to to return to main activity from any other activity. This way, you still restart the main activity but may not have to recreate it.

```
//In other activities    
case R.id.menu_Home: 
    finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

check that current activity is your `mainActivity` and then start the intent.

```
case R.id.menu_Home:
if(!(this.getClass().getSimpleName()==MainActivity)){
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_Home:
        if (!(this instanceof MainActivity)) {
            finish();
        }

        break;
    case R.id.settings:
        if (!(this instanceof Settings)) {
            if(!(this instanceof MainActivity))
                            finish();
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
```

The flow will be:

```
If
```

you are on MainActivity and mainActivity is selected do nothing

```
else
```

just finish what ever activity you are on.

```
If
```

you are on settings Activity and settings is selected do nothing

```
else if
```

you are on main activity and  just start Settings Activity

```
else
```

finish where ever you are and start settings.

```
Do same with others
```

This flow will ensure that you have only on main activity you never create it again.
You go to next activity and when-ever you return you finish that activity.